# Background Service to take picture with Camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-service

I know there are a lot of questions regarding this, but i think the problem i am facing is not addressed in any of them.
From all the different questions i wrote this Service. The problem is that i am getting "Success" in all the try-catch blocks in the onStartCommand method, but the logs in the Callback methods (ShutterCallback and PictureCallback) are not getting processed.
Which I think means that the picture is taken but the Callbacks are not called, which is weird.

```
Camera cam;
Parameters param;
PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.d("CAMERA", "onPictureTaken - raw");
    }
};

ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    public void onShutter() {
        Log.i("CAMERA", "onShutter'd");
    }
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
        cam = Camera.open();
        Log.i("CAMERA", "Success");
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.e("CAMERA", "Camera currently unavailable");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        param = cam.getParameters();
        cam.setParameters(param);
        Log.i("CAMERA", "Success");
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        Log.e("CAMERA", "Parameter problem");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(this);
        cam.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder());
        cam.startPreview();
        Log.i("CAMERA", "Success");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("CAMERA", "Surface Problem");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        cam.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, null);
        Log.i("CAMERA", "Success");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("CAMERA", "Click Failure");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    cam.release();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Comment: Follow this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631013/take-photo-from-camera-in-service/39632436#39632436

Answer (score 2):

You should not release the camera immediately after calling takePicture method. You need to give the camera enough time to execute the callbacks. BTW, you'd better to also add a JPG callback. Also stopPreview can be called before releasing camera. Your code could look like below:

```
Camera cam;
Parameters param;
PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.d("CAMERA", "onPictureTaken - raw");
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
    }
};

PictureCallback jpgCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.d("CAMERA", "onPictureTaken - jpg");
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
    }
};

ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    public void onShutter() {
        Log.i("CAMERA", "onShutter'd");
    }
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
        cam = Camera.open();
        Log.i("CAMERA", "Success");
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.e("CAMERA", "Camera currently unavailable");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        param = cam.getParameters();
        cam.setParameters(param);
        Log.i("CAMERA", "Success");
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        Log.e("CAMERA", "Parameter problem");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(this);
        cam.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder());
        cam.startPreview();
        Log.i("CAMERA", "Success");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("CAMERA", "Surface Problem");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        cam.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, null);
        Log.i("CAMERA", "Success");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("CAMERA", "Click Failure");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Commented out following line and moved it into your callbacks
    //cam.release();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Comment: Is `stopPreview` actually needed before releasing the camera?

Comment: I think you're spot-on about the need for a JPEG callback; the `takePicture` documentation implies that the other callbacks aren't supported on all devices.

Comment: `cam.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, null);` gives me an error. Runtime exception takepicture failed. Any idea whats up?

Answer (score 0):

You've missed these critical points:

1. The `SurfaceView` must be added to the WindowManager.
2. You didn't wait for the surface to be created before trying to use it. On the `view.getHolder()`, use `addCallback` and set and initialise the preview and take the photo in the callback's `surfaceCreated` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing "null" as third parameter in takePicture method which is belongs to PictureCallback.

Your code :

```
try {
        cam.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, null);
        Log.i("CAMERA", "Success");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("CAMERA", "Click Failure");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Change Like below :

```
try {
            cam.takePicture(shutterCallback,null,rawCallback);
            Log.i("CAMERA", "Success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("CAMERA", "Click Failure");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```